# Plant is suddenly losing all leaves

Tags: houseplants

My dieffenbachia is suddenly losing all its leaves. I’m not sure what’s going on. I watered it today after almost 8 days. It was doing good then. Had some new growth as well. But then started shedding like crazy! Any suggestions would be helpful

[image: dieffenbachia]

Comment: Have you recently moved it to a new location?

Comment: No it has always been on the same table.